No module named 'gi' after building onefile executable with PyInstaller
I'm trying to build my script written in Python into single file executable. When I used pyinstaller -F script.py on my computer, that's worked. But when I try to build executable by GitHub Workflows, after downloading generated binary I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "pydbus/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "pydbus/bus.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
[PYI-11218:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'script' due to unhandled exception!

pydbus need gi (GObject) to works, however I checked on workflow if it is installed and apt returned to me that python3-gi package is installed and up to date.
Before building ofc I upgrade pip, install dependencies from requirements.txt and install pyinstaller itself.
Here is fragment of my workflow:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name:  Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
          architecture: 'x64'
      - name:  Upgrade pip
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      - name:  Install dependencies
        run: python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name:  Install pyinstaller
        run: python -m pip install -U pyinstaller
      - name:  Build executable
        run: pyinstaller -F script.py

I really doesn't know what I should do with it. Thanks in advance for all forms of help.
EDIT: I found a solution. This error was caused by missing PyGObject in Python dependencies. After installing PyGObject, everything works fine.

This is happening because PyInstaller doesn’t automatically include system-installed libraries when bundling your Python script. You can explicitly add it using --hidden-import option, so your run command would be:
run: pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=gi script.py

Or you could use custom hook

I tried this but without any results, installing PyGObject fixed this error

Did it work without the --hidden-import option? Or you had to also add it?!
